# How to delete search suggestion on mac safari(iCloud)?

Tags: mac, icloud, safari

By"delete"I mean remove, not disable. I still want to keep that function for other sites. Just an annoying site keep bothering me when I search google in safari.

The search suggestion still exist after I removed all the history, bookmarks, readinglist. Even reinstall safari. It seems hide in icloud, not only in local mac.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try clearing the browsing data on all of your devices connected to that iCloud account. iCloud now syncs your bookmarks and history across all devices. It's possible that particular site suggestion is from a separate device.

Comment: I've tried that but problem still appears, Is there any way to totally remove all the safari data in iCloud?